# How to find from a list of Intervals, what is the maximum number of simultaneous Intervals at any time

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, jodatime, intervals

I am using `Java 11` with `SpringBoot` and making a request to `Elasticsearch` which returns a list containing several start and finish dates for operations happening during a single day. 
 Which I can use to create date Intervals with JodaTime. From there, I need to figure out what was the maximum number of simultaneous operations that happened during that day.

I can't think of an effective way to find that out aside from going through the day minute by minute and checking the amount at that time and if it is the biggest number. Is there a more effective way of doing it?

Comment: First, convert each interval (start_time, end_time) to two pairs (start_time,+1) and (end_time,-1).   Then sort the resulting pairs by their first (time) element.   Then go through the sorted list, keeping track of the running sum of +1's and -1's.   Then return the biggest value you've kept track of.

Comment: A notice at the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

*Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.*

Comment: Im not sure I understand, can you give an example?

Comment: thank you, I will change to JavaTime instead of joda, @ArvindKumarAvinash.

Comment: @MarkLavin so if i have intervals 1:00 - 2:00 and 1:30-2:30, I would turn that into [(1:00, +1), (1:30,+1)] and [(2:00,-1), (2:30,-1)]. summing all the +1s and -1s would always amount to 0. Am I understanding what you said wrong?

Comment: I get it now, thats a great solution, thanks a lot, @MarkLavin!!

Comment: @MarkLavin It seems you can post that as an answer.